# Create FunctionK instance with anonymous function

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I want to create a `FunctionK` instance with anonymous function. Here is the minimal example of that:

```scala
import cats.~>

given (Option ~> List) = {
  case Some(a) => a :: Nil
  case None    => Nil
}
```

However, this snippet throws compile error:

```
Missing parameter type

I could not infer the type of the parameter x$1
in expanded function:
  x$1 =>
  x$1 match 
    {
      case Some(a) =>
        a :: Nil
      case None =>
        Nil
    }
Expected type for the whole anonymous function:
  cats.arrow.FunctionK[Option, List]
```

Is the compiler not smart enough to infer all the types, or am I using anonymous function not the right way?

Compiled with `Scala==3.4.0-RC1` and `cats.core==2.10.0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's analyze it step by step.

`FunctionK` is actually not a function. In Scala 3-only world it could be defined as:

```scala
type FunctionK[F[_], G[_]] = [A] => F[A] => G[A]
```

which would make it a [polymorphic function type](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/new-types/polymorphic-function-types.html). But it was defined before Scala 3 became a thing and needs to be backward compatible with the old representation, that it:

```
trait FunctionK[F[_], G[_]] {

  def apply[A](fa: F[A]): G[A]
}
```

which was a Scala 2's workaround for not having polymorphic function types.

In situations like:

```
trait FunctionLike[A, B] {

  def method(a: A): B
}

val fl: FunctionLike[Int, String] = _.toString
```

we are using Single Abstract Method syntax - compiler sees that we are using lambda syntax for something where we could be using `new FunctionLike[Int, String] { ... }` but it also sees that this `trait`/`abstract class` has only 1 abstract method so it can assume that we want to implement the whole `trait`/`abstract class` by implementing this method (and so we can *pretend* that it's a function).

Thing is, SAM seems to be currently implemented only for normal (monomorphic) methods, and when you are using lambdas for polymorphic ones, it will not make the connection:

```
import cats.~>

given (Option ~> List) = [A] => (opt: Option[A]) => opt match {
  case Some(a) => a :: Nil
  case None    => Nil
}
// error:
// Found:    [A] => (opt: Option[A]) => List[A]
// Required: cats.arrow.FunctionK[Option, List]
```

In your case, you additionally used syntax for monomorphic function type: currently when you need a polymorphic function type you have to write: `[A] => (a: A) => ...` - type parameters have to be explicitly defined and explicitly used in one of the arguments.

*Gaël's answers explains how you can actually implements it.*

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, in this case the compiler cannot infer the types automatically.

You have to use the verbose syntax:

```scala
import cats.~>

given (Option ~> List) = new ~>[Option, List] {
  def apply[A](o: Option[A]): List[A] = o match {
    case Some(a) => a :: Nil
    case None => Nil
  }
}
```

*Mateusz' answer explains very well why :)*

Comment: It can be a little shorter on Scala 3, you can replace `given (Option ~> List) = new ~>[Option, List] {` with `given (Option ~> List) with` ([scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/MateuszKubuszok/Cvv1W1UdRnWfWt66k9A5Og/3)).